# Retrieve ASP.net DataList value with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to get the value of Datalist with javascript and display it with ASP label. How can I do that with javascript?

Below is my data inside Datalist:
[This data will bind to Datalist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw3WO.png)

My Javascipt code:

```
function checkHomestayName() 
{
    var homestayName = document.getElementById('<%=checkHomestayNameDataList.ClientID %>');
    var data = homestayName.rows[0].innerText;
    document.getElementById('<%=Label5.ClientID %>').innerText = data;
}
```

My HTML code:

`<asp:DataList ID="checkHomestayNameDataList" runat="server"></asp:DataList>`

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();

     dt = home.checkHomestayName();
     checkHomestayNameDataList.DataSource = dt;
     checkHomestayNameDataList.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: You can reduce your waiting by providing produced html code instead of providing server side code. Not everyone has a running aspnet enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

A DataList generates a html `table` element. So you need to search the contents of the indiviudal cells and use that content.

```
function checkHomestayName() {
    var data = '';
    var homestayName = $('#<%=checkHomestayNameDataList.ClientID %>');

    homestayName.find('td').each(function () {
        data += $(this).text();
    });

    console.log(data);
}
```

You may need to fine tune `homestayName.find('td')` depending on what is in your `ItemTemplate`.